# Unable to signup a new user in Cognito using Javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to signup/login users using Amazon Cognito. I've created a userpool in Cognito and using Javascript to get user details. But the function userPool.signup gives error code "Network error".

The Javascript code:

```
var login_form = new Vue({
el: '#sign',
data: {
    formOpen: false,
    v_name: '',
    v_email: '',
    v_mobile: '',
    v_password: '',
    productData: {
        title: 'HI',
        rating: '',
        price: '',
        list_price: '',
        is_featured: false
    }
},
methods: {
    resetForm: function () {
        this.productData = {
            title: '',
            rating: '',
            price: '',
            list_price: '',
            is_featured: false
        }
    },
    signup: function () {
        try {
            var poolData = {
                UserPoolId: 'us-east-1_fKUK4frdl',
                ClientId: '6jsaiafnffqd7bufnrq1mdb1nm'
            };

            var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);

            var username = this.v_email;
            var password = this.v_password;
            var attributeList = [];

            var dataEmail = {
                Name: 'email',
                Value: this.v_email
            };
            var dataPhoneNumber = {
                Name: 'phone_number',
                Value: this.v_mobile
            };
            var dataName = {
                Name: 'name',
                Value: this.v_name
            }
            var attributeEmail = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute(dataEmail);
            var attributePhoneNumber = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute(dataPhoneNumber);
            var attributeName = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute(dataName);
            attributeList.push(attributeEmail);
            attributeList.push(attributePhoneNumber);
            attributeList.push(attributeName);
            var cognitoUser;
            console.log("username:" + username);
            console.log("password:" + password);
            console.log("attributes:" + attributeList);
            userPool.signUp(username, password, attributeList, null, function (err, result) {
                if (err) {

                    console.log(err);
                    console.log("Error here");

                    alert(err);
                    return;
                }
                cognitoUser = result.user;
                console.log('user name is ' + cognitoUser.getUsername());
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            alert("Exception error");
        }
    },
    cancel: function () {
        this.formOpen = false;
        this.resetForm();
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log("Sign app mounted");
    }
}
})
```

The console output is as follows:

username:tempmail@mail.com ecommerce-main.js:193

password:temppassword@123 ecommerce-main.js:194

attributes:{"Name":"email","Value":"tempmail@mail.com"},{"Name":"phone_number","Value":"+919994443322"},{"Name":"name","Value":"Balaji"} ecommerce-main.js:198

{code: "NetworkError", name: "Error", message: "Network error"} ecommerce-main.js:199 
Error here

As suggested by a user in github, I've tried changing the Attribute settings in UserPool leaving everything unchecked in Username option. Yet, the same error persists. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Having the same issue - did you ever find a resolution for this?